# Low-resolution background image in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

When I try to import the image into Tableau as floating, the resolution becomes awful, how do I fix this? I have tried importing different file formats: png, and jpg of the same picture but the result is the same.

Comment: You can fit and center the image, then adjust the size

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with fixed image option.
or
Use horizontal/vertical container use it as fixed and then put image container  in it as floating.